# What is the meaning of 合 in 但也有多户合住一座四合院的情况?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

但也有多户合住一座四合院的情况，被称为“大杂院”，住户多为普通劳动人民。

This is from the Standard Course Book of HSK5, section 14.

What is the meaning of 合 (...户合住...)？My feeling is "together". Do you agree? Or it means something else (it has many definitions on dictionaries)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an adverb “jointly”  for the verb “live”  here

合 + v = [jointly + v] or [v + together]

> 但也有多户**合**住一座四合院的情况

But there are situations that multiple families **jointly** living in one 四合院

Meaning a few households sharing a 四合院